# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' in robot framework

Tags: python, json, rest, robotframework

Hi I am working in robot framework to test rest api.

here is my code.

```
*** Settings ***
Library               RequestsLibrary

*** Variables ***
${host}    https://test.net
${headers}    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=application/json;charset=utf-8       
x-system-id    SYSTEM222    x-api-key    
FA18269ABC02DBD


*** Test Cases ***
Do a GET Request and validate the response code and response body
Create Session    my_session    ${host}    
${response}    GET On Session   my_session   /v1/sync/users   headers=${headers}
Log to console    ${response}
```

While running the script I am getting the below error.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You write "here is my code" and then you include some text or output that isn't your code. Please edit your question to include (a) your code, and (b) the full traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: Please tell us which line of code is generating that error.

Comment: ${response}  part is throwing error

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to get items from a dict:

```
{'key': 'value'}.items()
```

Wich the output will be:

```
dict_items([('key', 'value')])
```

But instead of using this method on a dictionary, you are using on a string:

```
'some text'.items()
```

Error (the same as yours):

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Check why it is coming a string in this variable, and problem solved.

Comment: how to mention in this code. I am new and trying to solve the issue from last 2 days